# Need help for a precise MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

I need some help for a query.

First, here the tables:

```
--
-- Create table produit
--

CREATE TABLE produit (
     ref_prod integer primary key,
     name_prod text not null,   
     color text ,
     weight integer
);

--
-- Create table factory
--

CREATE TABLE factory (
    ref_factory integer primary key,
     name_factory text not null,
     city text not null
);

--
-- Create table shop
--

CREATE TABLE shop (
    ref_shop integer primary key,
     name_shop text not null,
     city text not null
);

--
-- Create table provenance
--

CREATE TABLE provenance (
    ref_prod integer,
    ref_factory integer,
    ref_shop integer,
    quantity integer,
    constraint cle_prim primary key (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop)
);

--
-- Data for Name: shop
--

INSERT INTO shop (ref_shop, name_shop, city) VALUES (14, 'Stock10', 'Paris');
INSERT INTO shop (ref_shop, name_shop, city) VALUES (16, 'JaiTout', 'Marseille');
INSERT INTO shop (ref_shop, name_shop, city) VALUES (18, 'EnGros', 'Bordeaux');
INSERT INTO shop (ref_shop, name_shop, city) VALUES (20, 'PrixBas', 'Toulouse');
INSERT INTO shop (ref_shop, name_shop, city) VALUES (22, 'BasPrix', 'Marseille');
INSERT INTO shop (ref_shop, name_shop, city) VALUES (24, 'DuBon', 'Lyon');
INSERT INTO shop (ref_shop, name_shop, city) VALUES (26, 'DuBeau', 'Toulouse');
INSERT INTO shop (ref_shop, name_shop, city) VALUES (28, 'BasDeGamme', 'Dublin');
INSERT INTO shop (ref_shop, name_shop, city) VALUES (30, 'PasCher', 'Lyon');


--
-- Data for Name: produit
--

INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (1, 'tabouret', 'rouge', 5);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (2, 'evier', 'bleu', 65);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (3, 'bureau', 'jaune', 45);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (4, 'lampe a petrole', 'vert', 15);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (5, 'ordinateur', 'rouge', 10);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (6, 'telephone', 'bleu', 8);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (7, 'tabouret', 'violet', 1);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (8, 'evier', 'bleu', 65);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (9, 'tabouret', 'orange', 3);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (10, 'lampe halogene', 'rose', 11);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (11, 'lampe a souder', 'noir', 3);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (12, 'telephone', 'bleu', 2);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (13, 'casse-noix', 'vert', 1);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (14, 'casse-pied', 'marron', 55);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, color, weight) VALUES (15, 'casse-oreille', 'violet', 15);

INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, weight) VALUES (16, 'casserole', 'bleu');
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, weight) VALUES (17, 'bottes', 'rouge');
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod) VALUES (18, 'lampe halogene');
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, weight, weight) VALUES (19, 'table', 'rouge', 10);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, weight) VALUES (20, 'telephone', 3);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, weight, weight) VALUES (21, 'evier', 'bleu', 65);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, weight) VALUES (22, 'evier', 105);
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, weight) VALUES (23, 'evier', 115);


--
-- Data for Name: provenance
--

INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (1, 109, 14, 80);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (1, 109, 16, 100);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (1, 302, 16, 213);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (2, 189, 30, 213);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (3, 402, 14, 315);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (4, 200, 18, 985);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (5, 302, 20, 858);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (6, 213, 16, 315);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (6, 109, 22, 458);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (7, 109, 16, 213);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (8, 302, 16, 2000);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (9, 189, 30, 175);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (10, 402, 14, 100);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (11, 109, 16, 750);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (11, 302, 16, 100);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (12, 189, 30, 315);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (12, 200, 16, 589);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (12, 189, 22, 213);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (13, 402, 14, 499);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (14, 109, 18, 213);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (15, 189, 20, 1958);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (15, 189, 16, 333);

INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (16, 302, 14, 49);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (17, 109, 18, 213);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (16, 189, 20, 18);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (16, 213, 16, 33);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (18, 200, 18, 187);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (18, 302, 16, 88);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (18, 213, 14, 315);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (20, 109, 22, 458);
INSERT INTO provenance (ref_prod, ref_factory, ref_shop, quantity) VALUES (20, 402, 14, 13);


--
-- Data for Name: factory
--

INSERT INTO factory (ref_factory, name_factory, city) VALUES (109, 'martin', 'Nantes');
INSERT INTO factory (ref_factory, name_factory, city) VALUES (189, 'leroux', 'Marseille');
INSERT INTO factory (ref_factory, name_factory, city) VALUES (213, 'dupont', 'Bordeaux');
INSERT INTO factory (ref_factory, name_factory, city) VALUES (402, 'peugeot', 'Toulouse');
INSERT INTO factory (ref_factory, name_factory, city) VALUES (200, 'peugeot', 'Marseille');
INSERT INTO factory (ref_factory, name_factory, city) VALUES (302, 'rover', 'Londres');



--
-- Name: provenance_ref_shop_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; 
--

ALTER TABLE provenance
    ADD CONSTRAINT provenance_ref_shop_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ref_shop) REFERENCES shop(ref_shop);


--
-- Name: provenance_ref_prod_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT;
--

ALTER TABLE provenance
    ADD CONSTRAINT provenance_ref_prod_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ref_prod) REFERENCES produit(ref_prod);


--
-- Name: provenance_ref_factory_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; 
--

ALTER TABLE provenance
    ADD CONSTRAINT provenance_ref_factory_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ref_factory) REFERENCES factory(ref_factory);
```

I need a query which give (x,y) shop's references which are supplied of the same product made by the same factory.
I must only use SELECT, WHERE and HAVING.

I started with something like:

```
SELECT shop.ref_shop AS "shop1",shop.ref_shop AS "shop2"
FROM shop,
     factory,
     provenance,
     produit
WHERE shop.ref_shop=provenance.ref_shop
    AND produit.ref_prod=provenance.ref_prod
    AND factory.ref_factory=provenance.ref_factory
    AND shop1<>shop2
```

but I don't know how only have shop's references which are supplied of the same product made by the same factory and its looks like aliases don't work with WHERE.

Comment: Please give some examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema itself for `produit` table is wrong. Column names must be unique in a table.

You can probable create something like

```
CREATE TABLE produit (
ref_prod integer primary key,
 name_prod text not null,   
 weight_text text,
 weight_int integer
);
```

The insert statements will need to changed accordingly, for example

```
INSERT INTO produit (ref_prod, name_prod, weight_text, weight_int) VALUES (12, 'telephone', 'bleu', 2);
```

> I need a query wich give (x,y) shop's references wich are supplied of the same product made by the same factory. I must only use SELECT, WHERE and HAVING.

It's important that you first attempt to write the query, then ask for help with any questions.

**Update:**

You cannot use aliasing names in where clause. The column name `shop.ref_shop` should be used instead.

Also, why are you selecting same column twice?

The

> ""

are not necessary in the `SELECT shop.ref_shop AS "shop1",shop.ref_shop AS "shop2"` as the alias doesn't have spaces.

Provide some sample output data that you expect the query to return.

Comment: You're right, I messed up with produit. I edit the question with the right schema and add my attempt at the end.

Comment: The Insert code for produit still shows duplicate column names. What is the output you are getting when you run the  SELECT?

Comment: "Unknown column 'shop1' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Example of request for the shops in relationship with produit 'tabouret' and factory 'martin'

```
    SELECT distinct
        shop.name_shop, produit.name_prod, factory.name_factory
    FROM
        shop,
        provenance,
        factory,
        produit
    WHERE
        shop.ref_shop = provenance.ref_shop
            AND factory.ref_factory = provenance.ref_factory
            AND produit.ref_prod = provenance.ref_prod
            AND produit.name_prod = 'tabouret'
            AND factory.name_factory = 'martin';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're after, but here's a basic query to get all the data (ignoring NULL values). You should be able to amend it to your needs...

```
       SELECT s.ref_shop 
            , s.name_shop  
            , s.city shop_city
            , v.ref_prod 
            , v.ref_factory 
            , v.quantity
            , p.name_prod
            , p.color
            , p.weight
            , f.name_factory 
            , f.city factory_city
         FROM shop  s
         JOIN provenance v 
           ON v.ref_shop = s.ref_shop
         JOIN produit p
           ON p.ref_prod = v.ref_prod
         JOIN factory f
           ON f.ref_factory = v.ref_factory;

+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+----------+-----------------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
| ref_shop | name_shop | shop_city | ref_prod | ref_factory | quantity | name_prod       | color  | weight | name_factory | factory_city |
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+----------+-----------------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|       14 | Stock10   | Paris     |        1 |         109 |       80 | tabouret        | rouge  |      5 | martin       | Nantes       |
|       16 | JaiTout   | Marseille |        1 |         109 |      100 | tabouret        | rouge  |      5 | martin       | Nantes       |
|       22 | BasPrix   | Marseille |        6 |         109 |      458 | telephone       | bleu   |      8 | martin       | Nantes       |
|       16 | JaiTout   | Marseille |        7 |         109 |      213 | tabouret        | violet |      1 | martin       | Nantes       |
|       16 | JaiTout   | Marseille |       11 |         109 |      750 | lampe a souder  | noir   |      3 | martin       | Nantes       |
|       18 | EnGros    | Bordeaux  |       14 |         109 |      213 | casse-pied      | marron |     55 | martin       | Nantes       |
|       18 | EnGros    | Bordeaux  |       17 |         109 |      213 | bottes          | NULL   |      0 | martin       | Nantes       |
|       22 | BasPrix   | Marseille |       20 |         109 |      458 | telephone       | NULL   |      3 | martin       | Nantes       |
|       30 | PasCher   | Lyon      |        2 |         189 |      213 | evier           | bleu   |     65 | leroux       | Marseille    |
|       30 | PasCher   | Lyon      |        9 |         189 |      175 | tabouret        | orange |      3 | leroux       | Marseille    |
|       22 | BasPrix   | Marseille |       12 |         189 |      213 | telephone       | bleu   |      2 | leroux       | Marseille    |
|       30 | PasCher   | Lyon      |       12 |         189 |      315 | telephone       | bleu   |      2 | leroux       | Marseille    |
|       16 | JaiTout   | Marseille |       15 |         189 |      333 | casse-oreille   | violet |     15 | leroux       | Marseille    |
|       20 | PrixBas   | Toulouse  |       15 |         189 |     1958 | casse-oreille   | violet |     15 | leroux       | Marseille    |
|       20 | PrixBas   | Toulouse  |       16 |         189 |       18 | casserole       | NULL   |      0 | leroux       | Marseille    |
|       18 | EnGros    | Bordeaux  |        4 |         200 |      985 | lampe a petrole | vert   |     15 | peugeot      | Marseille    |
|       16 | JaiTout   | Marseille |       12 |         200 |      589 | telephone       | bleu   |      2 | peugeot      | Marseille    |
|       18 | EnGros    | Bordeaux  |       18 |         200 |      187 | lampe halogene  | NULL   |   NULL | peugeot      | Marseille    |
|       16 | JaiTout   | Marseille |        6 |         213 |      315 | telephone       | bleu   |      8 | dupont       | Bordeaux     |
|       16 | JaiTout   | Marseille |       16 |         213 |       33 | casserole       | NULL   |      0 | dupont       | Bordeaux     |
|       14 | Stock10   | Paris     |       18 |         213 |      315 | lampe halogene  | NULL   |   NULL | dupont       | Bordeaux     |
|       16 | JaiTout   | Marseille |        1 |         302 |      213 | tabouret        | rouge  |      5 | rover        | Londres      |
|       20 | PrixBas   | Toulouse  |        5 |         302 |      858 | ordinateur      | rouge  |     10 | rover        | Londres      |
|       16 | JaiTout   | Marseille |        8 |         302 |     2000 | evier           | bleu   |     65 | rover        | Londres      |
|       16 | JaiTout   | Marseille |       11 |         302 |      100 | lampe a souder  | noir   |      3 | rover        | Londres      |
|       14 | Stock10   | Paris     |       16 |         302 |       49 | casserole       | NULL   |      0 | rover        | Londres      |
|       16 | JaiTout   | Marseille |       18 |         302 |       88 | lampe halogene  | NULL   |   NULL | rover        | Londres      |
|       14 | Stock10   | Paris     |        3 |         402 |      315 | bureau          | jaune  |     45 | peugeot      | Toulouse     |
|       14 | Stock10   | Paris     |       10 |         402 |      100 | lampe halogene  | rose   |     11 | peugeot      | Toulouse     |
|       14 | Stock10   | Paris     |       13 |         402 |      499 | casse-noix      | vert   |      1 | peugeot      | Toulouse     |
|       14 | Stock10   | Paris     |       20 |         402 |       13 | telephone       | NULL   |      3 | peugeot      | Toulouse     |
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+----------+-----------------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to simplify.  You have 3 lookup tables...  Products, Factories and Shops.
Then a table that lists all products that are offered by which shops that are produced by which factories.

Now, that said, your question itself is not really clear, but I am under the impression that you want to know which shops have available the exact same product produced by the same factory.

That said, start a simple query of WHAT products are DUPLICATED in the Provenance table based on product common product / factory WITHOUT respect to the shop.  Get a count by this group HAVING the count > 1.  This results in which products are sold by multiple shop locations.

lets look at the hierarchy of the tables to this starting with what is provided per lookup.

```
select
      PV.ref_prod,
      PV.ref_factory,
      count(*) as howManyShops
   from
      Provenance PV
   group by
      PV.ref_prod,
      PV.ref_factory
   having
      count(*) > 1
```

Now, if you want to get the values of these products, factories and shops, use this result and join it to the Provenance on the same product / factory, but NOW, join to the lookup tables for the respective descriptive components.  Something like.

```
select
      PV2.ref_prod,
      PV2.ref_factory,
      PV2.ref_shop,
      PV2.quantity,
      PR.name_prod,
      PR.color,
      PR.weight,
      F.name_factory,
      F.City,
      S.name_shop,
      S.City as ShopCity
   from
      ( select
              PV.ref_prod,
              PV.ref_factory,
              count(*) as howManyShops
           from
              Provenance PV
           group by
              PV.ref_prod,
              PV.ref_factory
           having
              count(*) > 1 ) DupQualified
         JOIN Provenance PV2
            on DupQualified.ref_prod = PV2.ref_prod
           AND DupQualified.ref_factory = PV2.ref_factory
           JOIN Produit PR
              on PV2.ref_prod = PR.ref_prod
           JOIN Factory F
              on PV2.ref_factory = F.ref_factory
           JOIN Shop S
              on PV2.ref_shop = S.ref_shop
   order by
      PR.name_prod,
      F.name_factory,
      S.name_shop
```

The final order by will show the all shops for a same product / factory next to each other before going to the next product / factory.

If I am incorrect on my assumptions of what you are looking for, let me know and please edit your original question with more details and the intended use of the output of the query.